# Why using Expanded make my text disappear?

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to edit some of my co-worker code to make it responsive, because it show many overflow on different screen size. The initial code is using Text wrapped with sized box with fixed size and I wanted to change it to wrapped with expanded so it will take space it needed and will not overflow, but the text disappear when I use expanded ? why is that ? how should I make my text responsive.

Here's my normal code:

```
  Row(children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.groups,
          color: accentColor,
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 15),
        SizedBox(
          width: 190,
          child: Text(
            'imSolver',
            style: primaryColor600Style.copyWith(
                fontSize: fontSize16),
          ).tr(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ]),
```

Changed it into using expanded:

```
    Row(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.groups,
            color: accentColor,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                'imSolver',
                style: primaryColor600Style.copyWith(
                    fontSize: fontSize16),
              ).tr(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent `Row` of the `Expanded` (wrapping the `Container`) must have a finite with. You can just wrap it in an `Expanded` like so:

```
 Row(children: [
    Expanded(
      child:   Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.groups,
            color: accentColor,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 15),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                'imSolver',
                style: primaryColor600Style.copyWith(
                    fontSize: fontSize16),
              ).tr(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),),
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Flexible** instead of **Expanded** and do provide **mainAxisSize** to the **Row** Widget.

```
 Row(children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.groups,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 15),
                              Flexible(
                                child: Text(
                                  'imSolver',
                                )
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ]),
```

Comment: What does the function off adding mainAxisSize ?

Comment: The mainAxisSize property determines how much space a Row can occupy on its main axes. The mainAxisSize property has two possible values: MainAxisSize.max, MainAxisSize.min. You can use it accordinlgy